# Splitting column values with Sybase and ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, sybase, coldfusion-8

I need to trim the date from a text string in the function call of my app.

The string comes out as `text//date` and I would like to trim or replace the date with blank space. The column name is `overall_model` and the value is `ford//1911` or `chevy//2011`, but I need the date part removed so I can loop over the array or list to get an accurate count of all the models.

The problem is that if there is a `chevy//2011` and a `chevy//2010` I return two rows in my table because of the date. So if I can remove the date and loop over them I can get my results of chevy there are 23 chevy models.

Comment: Webster, please note the [edits I've just made](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11494675/revisions) to your question - the title summarises the problem; the tags identify the key technologies; the question uses paragraphs and formatting to improve readability - all of these things make it vastly more likely that you will get useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Sybase in a while, but I remember its string functions are very similar to MS SQL Server.

If `overall_model` always contains "//", use `charindex` to return the position of the delimiter and `substring` to retrieve the "text" before it. Then combine it with a COUNT. (If the "//" is not always present, you will need to add a `CASE` statement as well).

```
   SELECT SUBSTRING(overall_model, 1, CHARINDEX('/', overall_model)-1) AS Model
          , COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRecords
   FROM  YourTable
   GROUP BY SUBSTRING(overall_model, 1, CHARINDEX('/', overall_model)-1)
```

However, ideally the "text" and "date" should be stored separately. That would offer greater flexibility and generally better performance.

Comment: Can I do a regular expression to remove the numbers and slashes?

Comment: The best solution to this issue is to redesign the database and put the year value in a separate column.

Comment: @Webster - Use a regex where? If you mean in SQL, it depends on whether Sybase supports them. In CF you could us list functions with `/` as the delimiter. But as both Scott and I mentioned, the best solution is to separate the values into two columns. You can easily do that via an UPDATE using the string functions above.